# No luck with image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I've been using the image slider from http://responsiveslides.com/ due to it's simplicity and it's exactly what I'm after.

So for the slider you have the HTML

```
<ul class="rslides">
  <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="3.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>
```

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

The main javascript file I felt is too long to put on here so if you could go through the source code instead, I'd appreciate that but apologies in advance. I also couldn't post it due to the reputation issue.

Now that the slider I'm using has been laid out, the issue I'm having is when I stick the HTML in the body my end result is image #1 without any movement so essentially just trying to suss out why.

I researched before via Stackoverflow to see a similar issue and saw changes made to the small script tag for the javascript function, however I updated these problems and it never changed anything.

Another thing to say is when I check the console it obviously states responsiveSlides is not a function, but when I check the console for the original slider locally, it's fully functional and console error free.

Any support will be gratefully appreciated, it's been tedious and hopefully it's a simple issue.

Regards.

Comment: you could create a snippet or fiddle that includes all your external scripts. this would greatly benefit your cause, as we could get right to it, instead of having to look through all of your code and "imagining" it running, or building a JSFiddle ourselves based on what we think is happening on your side

Comment: As Ben suggested, a JSfiddle would be helpful. Did you remember to include the script that you're trying to use? `<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I built a JSFiddle using the .js on github: http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/rfn7z5g2/

Comment: Only issue with JSFiddle is I have multiple css files which I guess may be the issue I'm unsure incase there is a parent CSS overwriting any of the CSS required for the image to change. I only have one js file that is external, the rest are locally on my directory. Yes Fata1Err0r the <script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script> is there.

Comment: I noticed your JSFiddle is practically having the issue I have. I have the external js library but other than that, I can't suss it out.

Comment: Yes, I didn't link to the fiddle as a solution then (that would have been an answer, not a comment). It was a base we could start working on, to take a look at what's going on.
I have located a problem and provided an answer below

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a jquery incompatibility issue at hand. The `responsiveslides.js` uses `$slide.size()`, whereas users with jQuery 1.8+ should use `$slide.length`.

`.size()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

use [this version I forked](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/svArtist/ResponsiveSlides.js/rewrite/responsiveslides.js) instead.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/rfn7z5g2/

Comment: Here's a temp URL to look at and see if it helps you any further.

http://209.126.112.94/~example/

Comment: wrap the function inside `$(document).ready(function(){ /////// code goes here /////// });` or the $(window).load suggestion that is already hinted at there. Or run it otherwise AFTER the list has been created (near the bottom of the document)

Comment: Tried them both and still no luck. Do you think anything is somewhat overlapping the code as in a parent js or css for example?

Comment: It's definitely not CSS, there is still the same javascript error ("TypeError: $(...).responsiveSlides is not a function"), which either means that jQuery couldn't find a match, or the function hasn't been declared. But I can see the .js library is loaded, so it must be the former. That typically happens when the code is run before the DOM is ready. Can you update your hanges to the temp live site? Currently, the function is not wrapped in a .ready type function there.

Comment: Did you just remove jQuery? It appears to be missing. Add back jQuery please (before the other libraries)
Also, now you have both assets/js/responsiveslides.min.js and assets/js/responsivesliderr.js. for debugging, remove responsiveslides.min.js.

Comment: Ok I'm adding the jQuery back in. Removing responsiveslides.min.js

Comment: before the other libraries, please. (well, at least before the slider library)
What browser are you using btw? You could troubleshoot it yourself by displaying the console and checking for errors yourself. Avoids overhead and gives you quick insight and a definitive error you can simply google, and maybe find an answer

Comment: This should conclude the answer. If I add the slider.js in-browser (so definitely after jQuery is loaded) and run the `.responsiveSlides()` function, it works on your site too.    (btw, I used the JS Environment in Firefox by shift+f4 and run `var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "assets/js/responsivesliderr.js";
$("head").append(s);  // load our library
$("#slider1").responsiveSlides();  // assign the function after everything is loaded`

Comment: using chrome, when you say before the other libraries, are you meaning to have the <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> higher up on the page? I may sound a little silly I'm just wondering what else would mean before the other libraries. I troubleshooted it today and was just getting the error that the responsiveSlider is not a function, but the exact same code was on the standard downloadable example on the website I linked above at the start and no errors.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant. Turn `
  <script src="assets/js/responsivesliderr.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` into `
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/responsivesliderr.js"></script>`. You used to get an error because `.size()` isn't a function anymore (as of 1.8+). Please tell me if this works for you, or if another error pops up

Comment: ok done that and same idea really. line 54 or if you're looking at source code, the script tag with a function inside the head tag is telling me that it's an error and responsiveSlider is not a function. i've updated it for you in regards to switching it around, though.

Comment: I fixed the issue, I added <script type="text/javascript">$.noConflict(true);</script> below the two script tags on footer and all things seem to be running well now. Appreciate your time my friend.

Comment: Great, I was just about to say that, that is the last pasrt of the puzzle. Your `js/theme.min.js` is tampering with a lot of jQuery functions and listeners, which is why it's loaded near the bottom of the page. Initializing your slider before those (`packages.min.js` and `theme.min.js`) are called (but after the elements are ready) works, too.

Comment: btw, if you accept this answer officially, more people will be able to profit from the updated verion of the slider